# Run jar with parameters in gradle

Tags: java, jar, parameters, gradle

I want to run a jar file with parameters located at C:/Users/nwuser/FitNesse/fitnesse-standalone.jar in my gradle script. I know how to do it without parameters:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task runJar(dependsOn:jar) << {
  javaexec { 
    main="-jar"; args "C:/Users/nwuser/FitNesse/fitnesse-standalone.jar"
  } 
}
```

But now I want to do something similiar like (if using the console):

```
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -c "FrontPage?suite&format=text"
```

How can I apply -c "FrontPage?suite&format=text" inside my gradle script?

Kind regards !

Comment: According to Gradle 4.3, "The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

args is an array, so simply supply your arguments as such:

```
task runJar(dependsOn:jar) << {
  javaexec { 
    main="-jar";
    args = [
            "C:/Users/nwuser/FitNesse/fitnesse-standalone.jar",
            "-c",
            "FrontPage?suite&format=text"
           ]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're *just* trying to run a FitNesse test suite with Gradle, you can add the FitNesse jar to your dependencies:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.fitnesse:fitnesse:20161106'
}
```

and define a `JavaExec` task like so:

```
task fitnesse(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

  main = 'fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain'

  args '-c', 'FrontPage?suite&format=text'
}
```

And then run:

```
$ gradle fitnesse
...
Executing command: FrontPage?suite&format=text
--------
0 Tests,        0 Failures      0.091 seconds.
```

Comment: In my case it failed with full package name, but it worked using just the class name:
`main = 'Main'`